# Reitz Representation Theorm[Rudin: Real and Complex Anlaysis (pg45)] Step VII

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[image]

Here is my problem. He says that $\{B_n\}$ being a disjoint sequence of members of $M_F$ implies that $B=\cup_1^{\infty} B_n\in M_F$. The problem is, I don't see how $\mu(B)<\infty$ is guaranteed.

Comment: What do steps $VI$ and $IV$ say? What are $\mathfrak M,\,\mathfrak M_F$ and $\mathcal M_F$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably at this step in the proof Rudin has already shown that $\mu$ is monotone, and that $\mu(K)<\infty$ for all compact sets $K$.

Then note that $B_n\subset K$ for all $n$ by construction, hence $B=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n\subset K$. Therefore $\mu(B)\leq \mu(K)<\infty$.